# Firefox/curl cant resolve domain where dig can

Tags: networking, ubuntu, firefox, dns

On my main Ubuntu 19.10 machine, I have a strange DNS issue with the HCL idea lab: Its not reachable in Firefox and `curl` because the host couldn't be resolved.

```
$ curl https://connections-ideas.hcltechsw.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: connections-ideas.hcltechsw.com
```

I assumed problems with my DNS server first, but `dig` could resolve it:

```
$ dig +short connections-ideas.hcltechsw.com
https://connections.ideas.aha.io.
35.171.201.123
```

It's also not working on my android cell phone, either with wifi or using mobile. Seems only affect the subdomain, since hcltechsw.com is no problem with browser and `curl`.

My company PC with corporate proxy is the only machine where it works for some magic reason.

### What I already tried

Found [a similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/335359/how-is-it-possible-that-i-can-do-a-host-lookup-but-not-a-curl) where the answears suggest to check `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. I had

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

inside, which I changed for testing purpose to

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal dns
hosts:          files dns
hosts:          dns
```

but it still doesn't work. Since it's [from a C library and not a daemon](https://serverfault.com/questions/76853/nsswitch-conf-is-there-a-daemon-i-need-to-restart), I haven't restarted anything.

Furthermore, I tried `curl -4` as well as `curl -6` to force ipv4/v6.

The only thing which works is `curl` against the IP:

```
curl -k https://35.171.201.123 -H "Host:connections-ideas.hcltechsw.com" --head
```

Used `-k` here just for testing purpose, since the certificate is not issued for the ip address it would for sure result in a mismatch.

Comment: If it wasn't obvious from my answer below, the error here is with the DNS record and the fact that someone put "https://" in them. Ask whoever is responsible for that DNS to read up on how they should look and fix it, probably just removing that part should solve it.

Comment: It was, I understood. See my comment on your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably an issue with the actual DNS record of that domain, because I'm getting the exact same issue:

```
$ dig connections-ideas.hcltechsw.com

; <<>> DiG 9.14.7 <<>> connections-ideas.hcltechsw.com
(...)
;; ANSWER SECTION:
connections-ideas.hcltechsw.com. 214 IN CNAME   https://connections.ideas.aha.io.
https://connections.ideas.aha.io. 3514 IN A 18.233.118.192
```

The URL above that has incorrectly been entered into the DNS record resolves to:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
connections.ideas.aha.io. 3600  IN  A   35.171.201.123
```

You can curl both IPs fine:

```
$ curl 18.233.118.192
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

```
$ curl 35.171.201.123
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

In short, that DNS record is a mess, that CNAME is for example not how you use them, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record -- having records that starts with "https://" is just abysmal.

A records need to point a clean domain to an IP (no protocol prefix), and the CNAME needs to point a clean domain to another clean domain.

Comment: I also did a full `dig` without `+short` but overlooked the protocol. Since it worked in our company on Win + Linux, I expected a problem in my network. It's not the A record but according to the CNAME record you're right, the `https://` shouldn't be there. Thanks for your hint! Seems like we're having a tolerating DNS server in our company, which may fix this issue. I'll check it there on monday.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as an answer.